# GWT Push Button Click Listerner Issue

Tags: gwt

I am trying to fire click Listener on GWT Push Button, but the listener fires only when my clicks on button text not on the button.

Comment: Please add some sourcecode that we can help you.

Comment: PushButton pb = new PushButton( new Image( "images/icons/icon_" + type + ".png" ), this );

Comment: Please add the click handler code...

Answer (score 0):

`ClickListener` is deprecated. Use `addClickHandler(ClickHandler)` instead.

This code works for me:

```java
PushButton b = new PushButton("Up text", "Down text");
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
});
```